# AppCompatActivity is not assignable to Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

After a year of coding in android and everything working perfectly till yesterday. Today, I found something really strange after upgrading to gradle 3 alpha 2 and studio 3 build 2.

This is the declaration of one of the activities throwing error:
[image: This]

This is the activity code:
 [image: This]

What is wrong?

**EDIT**

appcompat dependency:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Comment: maybe is the dependencies problem ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I don't think so. Let me post dependecies.

Comment: Why downvote? This is a genuine question and serious trouble I am facing

Comment: can you run your program and show the full errors?

Comment: @JohnJoe I haven't run the program. Actually this is a production work code so I can't run right now

Comment: Looks to me like the AppCompatActivity class got messed up. Especially since it can't resolve the shared preferences method

Comment: @cricket_007 I too think so. But is it possible?

Comment: post full androidMainfest

Comment: @JohnJoe I can't its a production code. I can't breach privacy policy. Let me know what information you want

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use preview and alpha builds with production code. Downgrade

Comment: @cricket_007 ok. I will downgrade

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using Android Studio 3.1.2.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help:

In the app build.gradle, change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 25.

Also upgrade the version of the appcompat library to 25.3.1:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

UPDATE 05/31/2017:

As @cricket_007 pointed out to me in comments, it isn't caused by a problem with the non-existence of AppCompatActivity, as I had theorized (in comments).

And while I have not been able to track it down, it looks like the lint checking is behaving differently or misbehaving on Android Studio 3 Preview, or in the 3.0.0 alpha2 version of Android Gradle Plugin, some build tools versions (or *somewhere*).

If your code is compiling ok (in spite of the "assignable" complaint appearing in AndroidManifest.xml) and you want to keep using Android Studio 3 Preview, maybe it's worth trying to suppress "AndroidDomInspection" on that activity tag for now:

```
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<activity android:name=".admin.AdminChangeCoach">
    . . .
</activity>
```

But, FWIW, I also agree with @cricket_007's earlier comment: I'm not using Android Studio 3 for production yet either.

Comment: I have other dependencies and changing version conflicts build.

Comment: Ok. How about just changing compileSdkVersion to 25 and using appcompat library version 25.3.1 ?  Or, are you saying that other dependencies in your build.gradle require the earlier version of appcompat?

Comment: Yes @albert other dependencies are using earlier versions which is causing conflict

Comment: I believe one of the issues you face is that AppCompatActivity was added in version 24.2.0 (See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html ), but, at the same time, you also need to use the appcompat library version 23.2.1.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I didn't get you. I had the same dependency before upgrading build tools

Comment: @albert It was released with API 21, so that page seems wrong

Comment: @cricket_007 ah. good point. thank you. AppCompatActivity did exist before 24.2.0, so my theory must be wrong. here's another theory: something's wrong in the lint checking being done by Android Studio 3.0 (or the 3.0.0-alpha2 Gradle Android plugin). i'll update my answer to suggest temporarily suppressing that particular lint check. again, thanks.

Comment: Changing the targetSDKVersion and appcompat version fixed it. But do you know if there is an open bug report for them? I don't remember reading anywhere that for the Android Studio 3, then min supported target sdk will be 25.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I have not seen a bug report for this issue. I do not believe that the min supported target is sdk 25 for AS 3, either. I wish I had a better explanation for why upgrading to appcompat-v7:25.3.1 and upgrading targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 25 worked for this problem. My best guess is that one of the inspections or lint checks had a bug, and that this inspection or lint check was fixed somehow by upgrading compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and/or the appcompat lib version.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative ways, you can simply change the class that you extended to `Activity` class instead of `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I did that but that is a workaround. I am not understanding reason for this.

Comment: It is just because of difference classes and themes between support_v7 and normal android app. If you changed like this you should also change the AppTheme in style.xml

Comment: I am having Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar as parent theme and I think it is compatible with appcompatactivity. Is it wrong?