# Android Studio 3.0 JDK error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, java-home, android-studio-3.0

Today,I started getting this error:[image]

I changed the path in JAVA_HOME. JDK settings has correct path. Android Studio 3.0 is really buggy in canary build. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44252825/3484668) is my another question regarding Android Studio 3.0 bug. Also, where should I file these bugs?

**EDIT:**
JDK settings:
[image]

Comment: Post your jdk settings

Comment: @mike_d_boss I posted settings

Comment: Did you try changing the path to C:/Programs.... In your android studio

Comment: install jdk in C drive then set path in android studio

Comment: @mike_d_boss it says expecting in D:\D\.. but found in C:/ why should I change? Path is correct